# Integrals homework help question

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, indefinite-integrals

[image]

My question is about number **17.** It shows the question first then next step it goes to $\frac{1}{x^2}$. Can't I just leave that as is instead of making it $x^{-2}$, take anti derivative which is $\ln (x^2)$?

Comment: No, the antiderivative of $\frac{1}{x^2}$ is not $\ln x^2$.

Comment: Note that the antiderivative is only $\ln|x|+C$ for functions in the form $\frac{1}{x^p}$ when $p=1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

we have $$-\int x^{-2}dx$$ from $$\int x^{n}dx=\frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}+C$$ if $$n\ne -1$$ we get $$x^{-1}+C$$

Answer (score 1):

The antiderivative of $1/x^2$ is not $\ln x^2$.  In general, the antiderivative of $1/\mbox{crud}$ is not $\ln \mbox{crud}.$  Only the antiderivative of $1/x$ is $\ln x$.